# Finding duplicates in a row

Tags: sql

I have a table named TEST. Some fields have NULL value

```
Country City   Street   House
US      NULL   Avenue   14
UK      London NULL     15
NULL    NULL   NULL     NULL
NULL    NULL   Central  16
```

I need to display items with only one NULL.

So the output should be:

```
Country City   Street House
US      NULL   Avenue 14
UK      London NULL   15
```

I have stupid solution just compare all possible pairs of columns and check NULL.

Just like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM TEST
 WHERE NOT (
 (country='NULL' AND city='NULL')
 OR (country='NULL' AND street='NULL')
 OR (coutry='NULL' AND house='NULL')
 OR (city='NULL' AND street='NULL')
 OR (city='NULL' AND house='NULL')
 OR (street='NULL' AND house='NULL')
 )
```

It works, but understand that it is very inefficient.

Can you recommend more elegant solution ?

Comment: just for note:  I think your conditions should uses the form `country IS NULL` instead of `country = 'NULL'` because null is not a string but a very particular value. You should also precise (at least in tags) if you uses mysql or ms sql, which have different syntax.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from TEST
WHERE  
  CASE WHEN country = 'NULL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN city= 'NULL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN Street = 'NULL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN House = 'NULL' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I would test if sum `< 2`, not `= 1`

Comment: I think it should be `when country IS NULL` - not a string comparison

Comment: I agree with @FlorinGhita , = 1 will eliminate rows with no NULL values at all.

Comment: <2 will not give any advantage, it will also select records if the count of NULL records is 0.  <2 is a different condition to = 1.  If you read the question he wants to list records with ONE null value, not zero null values

Comment: IS NULL is the ISO/ANSI preferred method, but the questioner was using = 'NULL' which can still be used in some SQL version

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from test1 
where
length(nvl(country,'@')||nvl(City,'@')||nvl(street,'@')||nvl(house,'@'))-
length(replace(nvl(country,'@')||nvl(City,'@')||nvl(street,'@')||nvl(house,'@'),'@',null))=1
```